# Event "mousedown" not working for left click in flickity

Tags: javascript

I have a code:
[example-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InD5s.png)
When I use flickity, I try using event "mousedown" for ".flickity-viewport", it doesn't work for left click. Please help me? Thanhks.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

See if `mouseup` works.

```
    .addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  var e = e || window.event;
  var btnCode;
  
  btnCode = e.button;

  switch (btnCode) {
    case 0:
      console.log('Left button clicked.');
      break;

    case 1:
      console.log('Middle button clicked.');
      break;

    case 2:
      console.log('Right button clicked.');
      break;

    default:
      console.log('Unexpected code: ' + btnCode);
  }
})
```